# Handling 'Object of type SimpleUploadedFile is not JSON serializable' error in Django DRF tests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If you're working with nested parameters in Django and experiencing difficulties while testing, you can pass the data for the nested structure using dictionaries or JSON objects. Here's an example of how you can do it:

models.py

```
class AlProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('product name', max_length=100)
    brand_id = models.ForeignKey(
        AlBrand,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="brand_id"
    )
    purchase_count = models.IntegerField('purchase count', default=0)
    custom_yn = models.CharField('customizable', max_length=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('created date', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('last updated date', auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.CharField('active', max_length=1)

class AlProductImage(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(
        AlProduct,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="product_id"
    )
    image_name = models.CharField('image name', max_length=255)
    image_src = models.FileField('product image', max_length=1000, upload_to="products")

class AlProductOption(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(
        AlProduct,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column="product_id"
    )
    options = models.CharField('options with comma', max_length=500)
    option_length = models.IntegerField('option length', default=1)
    is_active = models.CharField('active', max_length=1)
    is_direct_delivery = models.CharField('Direct delivery availability', max_length=1)
    is_custom = models.CharField('customizable', max_length=1)
    price = models.FloatField('product option`s price')
    delivery_fee = models.FloatField('product option`s delivery fee')
    direct_delivery_fee = models.FloatField('product option`s direct delivery fee')
    quantity = models.IntegerField('qunatity')
```

serializer.py

```
class ProductImageCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AlProductImage
        fields = [
            'image_name',
            'image_src'
        ]
        
class ProductOptionCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    option_length = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = serializers.CharField(default='y')
    is_direct_delivery = serializers.CharField(default='n')
    is_custom = serializers.CharField(default='n')
    
class ProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    brand_id = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    purchase_count = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    custom_yn = serializers.CharField(default='n')
    is_active = serializers.CharField(default='y')
    options = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=ProductOptionCreateSerializer(),
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
    )

    images = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=ProductImageCreateSerializer(),
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
    )
```

tests.py

```
class ProductTest(MainScenarioTest):
    def create_product(self, data):
        res = self.client.post(
            path='/product/product/',
            data=data,
            content_type='application/json',
        )

        return res

    def test_product_create(self):
        brand = 1

        input_data = dict(
            name='test product',
            brand_id=brand,
            options=[
                {
                    'options': "test_option",
                    'option_length': 100,
                    'price': 500,
                    'delivery_fee': 300,
                    'direct_delivery_fee': 300,
                    'quantity': 300,
                },
                {
                    'options': "test_option",
                    'option_length': 100,
                    'price': 500,
                    'delivery_fee': 300,
                    'direct_delivery_fee': 300,
                    'quantity': 300,
                }
            ],
            images=[
                {
                    'image_name': 'test_image_1.jpg',
                    'image_src': SimpleUploadedFile(
                        'test_image_1.jpg',
                        open(os.path.join('test_imgs', 'hanssem.jpg'), 'rb').read()
                    )
                }
            ]
        )

        res = self.create_product(input_data)
        print(res)
```

I have an error [Object of type SimpleUploadedFile is not JSON serializable]

I tried encoding it in base64, but it failed because the image_src field is of type FileField.
I also tried using multipart encoding, but it failed with an error stating that the bytes type does not have a key.